# Maintain variable status in a library

Tags: c

I am making a library which is basically a proxy, it is done this way:

```
socket s = -1;

void sendData(data){
   if(s == -1)
         s = createSocket();

}
```

strangely createSocket is called each time sendData is called, socket status is not maintained...why? On server side I get that socket is closed after sending data, so s is actually closed...

edit:
this is the signature of create socket:

```
SOCKET createSocket()
```

Answer (score 7):

You never update the value of `s` in your code.  `createSocket` appears to take a `socket` argument by value.  This means it will operate on a local copy of `s`, not the global member you intended to update.

You'll need to change the signature of `createSocket` like

```
socket createSocket(void);
...
s = createSocket();
```

or

```
createSocket(socket* s);
...
createSocket(&s);
```

instead